# How to enter long Number in Single Cell and Add them without chaning the value or cell format

Tags: excel

I am facing a small issue with excel. I have a worksheet that I want to use as adding a large number value but when I am entering a large number its changes to a different value format. Let me show you, please.

[image]

My question is how I can get the cell values like in Column D and sum them all. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: This is happening because Numeric precision limitation in Excel. Excel can show up to 15 significant digits. Read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel#:~:text=Although%20Excel%20can%20display%2030,%2C%20truncation%2C%20and%20binary%20storage.).

Comment: If you can find online the `xNumbers` add-in for Excel, it can handle greater precision than native Excel.  If you cannot find that or something similar, you will need to write your own VBA tool, or use a different program.